# ASP.NET MVC5: Want to update several items in Collection with model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

So I have a Collection of User objects, which should be mass-editable (edit many users at the same time). I'm saving the user input to the database using Entity Framework.

The collection the controller method gets from the form is null. Why?
Also, is the BindAttribute possible to use with collections like in my code?

## View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.User>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUsers", "Users"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Birth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Birth)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Update user data"/>
}
```

## Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UpdateUsers([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,Birth")] IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (User u in users)
        {
            db.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("EditUsers");
}
```

Comment: You need an [HttpGet] method to pre-populate the view before you make changes.

Comment: @Andrew Your update is a different question to your original one. I would create a new one or people may be put off answering a moving target.

Comment: @hutchonoid Okay, I removed the update from the original question.

Comment: @Komengem I assume your comment was regarding the other error maybe, which I removed from the post. Anyhow I solved that as well, it was due to a missing Id in the form, which made EF not be able to save the object to the db. The accepted solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to index your collection with a `for` rather than a `foreach` in order for the ModelBinder to pick it up:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Birth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Birth)
    }
```

Comment: Yes I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work in such a simple manner. I get this, what's the solution?

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain.User>'

Comment: @Andrew Your model needs to be a `List` not an IEnumerable.

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing the model to `List` before, but VS fooled me and I gave up. I closed and reopened the .cshtml file in the editor this time, and no more errors. :)