# MVC5 Bind form post to collection - coming up null

Tags: c#, collections, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I am just attempting to bind a collection from a form post. My collection in the model is a different name than what I'm trying to bind to, which my be the cause of the issue. I had this working, and then it stopped. I cannot find what changed to make it stop.

I thought my question was similar to this one:
[ASP.NET MVC5: Want to update several items in Collection with model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915249/asp-net-mvc5-want-to-update-several-items-in-collection-with-model-binding)

And I have read this a few times (Scott Hanselman can be counted on to give a clear picture of such things): 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Here's some code:

```
public class AttestModel
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public List<AccountSimpleDetail> AccountSimpleDetails { set; get; }
}

public class AccountSimpleDetResponseModel
{
    public int AccountSimpleDetailId { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
}

public partial class AccountSimpleDetail :   
{

  public int AccountSimpleDetailId { get; set; }
  public int? SaqSimpleQuestionId { get; set; }
  public int? SaqAnswerId { get; set; }


  ...More fields go on here
 }
```

In the View I have:

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AccountSimpleDetails.Count(); i++)
 {
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AccountSimpleDetails[i].AccountSimpleDetailId)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AccountSimpleDetails[i].AnswerId)
 }
```

I have some Javascript to handle clicking on a bunch of buttons in the browser which sets the AnswerId in the hidden fields. This is working fine.

The markup produced looks like this:

```html
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AccountSimpleDetailId must be a number." data-val-required="The AccountSimpleDetailId field is required." id="AccountSimpleDetails_1__AccountSimpleDetailId" name="AccountSimpleDetails[1].AccountSimpleDetailId" type="hidden" value="71" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AnswerId must be a number." id="AccountSimpleDetails_1__AnswerId" name="AccountSimpleDetails[1].AnswerId" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

The method signature looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Attest(int id, List<AccountSimpleDetResponseModel> AccountSimpleDetails)
```

What I used previously (which stopped working) is:

```
public ActionResult Attest(int id, [Bind(Prefix = "AccountSimpleDetails")] List<AccountSimpleDetResponseModel> simpleDetails)
```

The result of the bind is always null.

I know when I get to the point where I try something, it doesn't work, I try something else...  it simply means I am missing some fundamental point. Thank you for your time.

### EDIT

Here is the post request (Raw from Watchlist):

```
AccountSimpleDetails%5b1%5d.AccountSimpleDetailId=165&AccountSimpleDetails%5b1%5d.AnswerId=1&AccountSimpleDetails%5b2%5d.AccountSimpleDetailId=166&AccountSimpleDetails%5b2%5d.AnswerId=1&AccountSimpleDetails%5b3%5d.AccountSimpleDetailId=167&AccountSimpleDetails%5b3%5d.AnswerId=1&AccountSimpleDetails%5b4%5d.AccountSimpleDetailId=168&AccountSimpleDetails%5b4%5d.AnswerId=1&DXScript=1_171%2c1_94%2c1_93%2c17_33%2c17_2%2c1_152%2c1_164%2c1_91%2c1_156%2c1_101%2c17_7%2c1_154%2c1_103%2c1_102%2c17_8%2c1_114%2c1_121%2c1_169%2c1_138%2c1_170%2c1_124%2c17_9%2c1_163%2c1_162%2c1_147%2c17_32%2c1_157%2c1_98%2c1_125%2c1_104%2c1_166%2c1_139%2c17_13%2c1_97%2c1_141%2c1_142%2c17_15%2c1_155%2c1_143%2c1_144%2c17_16%2c17_17%2c1_126%2c17_11%2c1_146%2c1_149%2c17_20%2c1_160%2c17_22%2c1_158%2c1_153%2c1_161%2c17_25%2c1_165%2c17_28%2c17_31%2c1_100%2c5_5%2c5_4%2c4_11%2c4_10%2c4_6%2c4_7%2c4_9%2c17_14%2c4_12%2c1_113%2c1_116%2c4_13%2c4_14%2c1_110%2c1_112%2c1_137%2c17_12%2c1_159%2c7_49%2c7_47%2c7_51%2c17_21%2c1_105%2c1_108%2c1_117%2c17_0%2c1_120%2c1_106%2c17_1%2c1_107%2c17_3%2c1_109%2c1_122%2c17_5%2c1_145%2c1_119%2c17_18%2c17_19%2c1_118%2c17_29%2c1_123%2c10_2%2c10_1%2c10_3%2c10_4%2c17_4%2c9_23%2c9_22%2c9_24%2c17_24%2c9_13%2c9_10%2c9_8%2c17_23%2c9_12%2c9_9%2c9_15%2c9_11%2c1_96%2c8_10%2c8_17%2c8_24%2c8_26%2c8_9%2c8_12%2c8_13%2c8_18%2c17_26%2c8_21%2c8_23%2c8_22%2c8_16%2c8_19%2c8_20%2c8_14%2c8_15%2c8_25%2c8_11%2c6_12%2c17_30%2c16_16%2c16_18%2c16_14%2c16_11%2c16_19%2c16_6%2c16_15%2c16_8%2c16_12%2c16_13%2c16_7%2c17_27%2c16_17&DXCss=http%3a%2f%2ffonts.googleapis.com%2fcss%3ffamily%3dOpen%2bSans%3a300%2c400%2c600%2c700%2c800%257CShadows%2bInto%2bLight%2c%2fContent%2fbootstrap.min.css%2c%2fContent%2fMainSite.css%2c%2fContent%2fSiteAdjustments.css%2c%2fContent%2ffont-awesome.min.css%2c1_12%2c1_14%2c0_863%2c0_859%2c1_10%2c0_695%2c1_5%2c0_697%2c0_703%2c0_706%2c0_823%2c0_813%2c0_861%2c0_709%2c4_2%2c0_711%2c5_1%2c0_794%2c0_776%2c0_778%2c7_1%2c7_0%2c1_1%2c0_671%2c9_18%2c9_19%2c9_21%2c9_20%2c0_888%2c9_17%2c0_890%2c0_790%2c8_2%2c0_792%2c8_0%2c0_810%2c6_2%2c0_812%2c0_796%2c16_2%2c0_798
```

Comment: Could you show us content of POST request to this Action?

Comment: I added the post request to the question. Sorry it took so long. I had to resort to a work around of parsing it in my own code. But in the future I would really like to take advantage of all the libraries MS provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You binding your controls to properties of `AttestModel` so just post back the model

```
public ActionResult Attest(AttestModel model)
```

and the `AccountSimpleDetails` property will be correctly bound to the collection. However looking at your edited post request, it appears that the indexers are starting at `1`, not `0` (i.e. the first one is `AccountSimpleDetails[1].AccountSimpleDetailId=165...`. Do you have any javascript that deletes items in the collection? If so it will not bind the collection because indexers are zero based (and must be consecutive) so you will need to add an additional control for the index property.

Comment: I am doing: 

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AccountSimpleDetails[i].AccountSimpleDetailId)

I have no idea why the indexes on the hidden fields end up starting at 1. Odd behavior. 

Also, I shouldn't have to bind to the model in the view. I should be able to bind to any collection I want right?

Comment: You must have some javascript that is either removing or disabling the  controls for the first item in the collection which in turn causes the `DefaultModelBnder` to fail. Either that or your code is actually `for(var i = 1; i < Model.AccountSimpleDetails....)`. Not sure what you mean by _I shouldn't have to bind to the model in the view_ - that's what you are doing!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You must be right about something nuking the first item in the list. Or at least reordering them. If I have 3 items in the collection, 3 items are output. But starting with an Index of 1. 


In any MVC action it is stateless (as it should be). I take a model and populate it, give it to a view which outputs a bunch of text to a browser. It doesn't matter what model you used to fill in the form to begin with. You could hardcode them if you wished.

Comment: Oh and I don't want to parse the entire model. Just a collection that was in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

```
 @for (int x = 0; x < Model.AccountSimpleDetails.Count(); x++)
 {
      <span>@x</span>
 }
```

And it returns:
1,2, 3

That is the reason for the parsing issues as Stephen pointed out. So that's the real issue.

Thanks